# Дано целое число n и вещественное число x, |x| < 1

Tags: python

Дано целое число n и вещественное число x, |x| < 1 . Вычислить сумму n первых членов ряда x - x^2\2 + x^3\3 - x^4\4+... Полученное число должно являться приближенным значением функции f(x) = ln(x + 1), поэтому вывести так же значение функции  f(x) = ln(x + 1) в точке x. использовать  циклы, и прописать в комментариях рекуррентную формулу. Без функции math

```
n = int(input("Введите целое число n: "))
x = float(input("Введите вещественное число x (|x| < 1): "))

sum = 0
term = 0

for i in range(1, n+1):
    term = ((-1) ** (i-1)) * (x ** i) / i
    sum += term

print("Сумма n первых членов ряда:", sum)

# Вычисление значения функции f(x) = ln(x + 1)
f_x = 0
for i in range(1, n+1):
    f_x += ((-1) ** (i-1)) * (x ** i) / i

print("Значение функции f(x) = ln(x + 1) в точке x:", f_x)
```

Моя программа работает неправильно

Comment: А как правильно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите, в чём ваша проблема?
У вас код не так работает (что именно не так?)/выдаёт ошибку или что-то ещё?
Добавьте это информацию в вопрос с помощью кнопки [edit]. 
И помните, что вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») 
должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и 
*минимальный* код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного 
описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать [mcve].

Comment: Не используйте имя встроенной функции `sum` в качестве имени своей переменной. Используйте либо `summ` либо `sum_`

Answer (score 1):

Возводить в степень x не надо, достаточно умножать на -x.

Более выгодно сохранять числитель, и каждый раз делить на новый знаменатель, но раз уж у вас рекуррентность так задана, то пусть будет умножение-деление.

А вот для сравнения с логарифмом всё-таки нужно использовать math

```
summa = 0
term = x

for i in range(1, n+1):
    summa += term
    term *= -x * i / (i+1)

print("Сумма n первых членов ряда:", summa)

# Вычисление значения функции f(x) = ln(x + 1)
from math import log
print("Значение функции f(x) = ln(x + 1) в точке x:", log(x+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но возможно ошибка в знакопеременности в формуле.
Нужно заменить `(-1) ** (i-1) на (-1) ** i` в обоиъх циклах (в расчете суммы ряда и в вычислении значения функции f(x)).
Когда i равно 1, то знак должен быть положительным, поскольку член ряда начинается с x^1. То есть, у нас должно быть (-1) ** 1, что даст -1 возведённое в любую нечетную степень

Попробуйте исправить ваш цикл:

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    term = ((-1) ** i) * (x ** i) / i
    sum += term
```

И второй цикл:

```
# Вычисление значения функции f(x) = ln(x + 1)
f_x = 0
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    f_x += ((-1) ** i) * (x ** i) / i
```

Comment: При иксе теперь минус получился.